# Problemas sobre Contact form 7 wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin

queria comentaros una duda o un problema que tengo, a ver si me podeis ayudar, tengo un wordpress con el famoso contact form 7 para crear formularios, ahora mismo tengo validado los formularios que necesito de manera correcta y no me detecta error alguno, pero cuando relleno los campos y le doy a enviar, se queja de que no puede enviar el mail, mi pregunta es o duda, necesito configurar alguna cosa especifica dentro del wordpress para poder enviar mensajes sin necesidad de ningun pluguin de control de mails, tipo easy mail smtp o algunos asi, porque con ellos tampoco consigo resolver nada..., gracias!!! =D por cierto, la version del wordpress es la ultima (la 4.9.8) que ha salido, y he probdo a desactivar todos los pluguin y temas para a ver si hacia eso, nada... uso un tema comprado en themeforest... =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para trabajar con CF7 necesitas hacer el siguiente proceso :

1. Crea una cuenta de email dentro del servidor por
   ejemploinfo@sitio.com
2. Configura CF7 con esa cuenta creada, que
   exista físicamente dentro del servidor.
3. Si al realizar estos 2 pasos sigue sin funcionar, verifica que tu servidor este enviando correos correctamente, lo    puedes hacer con el siguiente código :

*Creas un archivo email.php en la raíz de tu servidor y lo accedes desde el navegador sitio.com/email.php si te genera "Mail sent OK" va todo bien con el servicio de correo.

```
<?php
/*
From http://www.html-form-guide.com 
This is the simplest emailer one can have in PHP.
If this does not work, then the PHP email configuration is bad!
*/
$msg="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    /* ****Important!****
    replace name@your-web-site.com below 
    with an email address that belongs to 
    the website where the script is uploaded.
    For example, if you are uploading this script to
    www.my-web-site.com, then an email like
    form@my-web-site.com is good.
    */

    $from_add = "info@sitio.com"; 

    $to_add = "tucorreo@personal.com"; //<-- put your yahoo/gmail email address here

    $subject = "Test Subject";
    $message = "Test Message";

    $headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";


    if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
    {
        $msg = "Mail sent OK";
    } 
    else 
    {
       $msg = "Error sending email!";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test form to email</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $msg ?>
<p>
<form action='<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
</p>


</body>
</html>
```

4. Si sigue sin funcionar, debes configurar un plugin de SMTP https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ para que los correos salgan autenticados desde tu servidor hacia cualquier servicio de correo y no tengas problemas de envíos de correos.

Apoyate en la documentación oficial del plugin : https://wpforms.com/how-to-send-wordpress-emails-with-mailgun/